# Authentication Issues with Profiles and session issues passport.js/Node.js

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

I'm currently trying to use passport for authentication for my node.js web application.  However, I'm having issues with the session data being stored properly.  At the moment, it's not being stored at all.

App.js

```
// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session
```

passport.js

```
var users = [
{ id: 1, username: 'bob', password: 'secret', email: 'bob@example.com' },
{ id: 2, username: 'joe', password: 'birthday', email: 'joe@example.com' }
];

function findById(id, fn) {

    fn(null, users[1]);
}

module.exports = function(passport, db) {
 // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log("serialization" + JSON.stringify(user, null, 4));
        done(null, user.personnel_id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
      findById(id, function (err, user) {
            console.log("deserialization" + JSON.stringify(user, null, 4));

            done(err, user);
        });

    });
```

routes.js

```
    app.post('/login',  passport.authenticate('local-login', 
    { 
        successRedirect: '/profile',
        failureRedirect:'/login', 
        failureFlash: true,
        badRequestMessage: 'Please enter your account credentials to login.'
    }));
    // =====================================
    // PROFILE SECTION =====================
    // =====================================
    // we will want this protected so you have to be logged in to visit
    // we will use route middleware to verify this (the isLoggedIn function)
    app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        console.log("req query:" +  JSON.stringify(req.query, null, 4));
        console.log("req body:" +  JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4));

        res.render('profile.jade', {
            user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
        });
    });
```

In the code above, the following code executes in this order

- User authenticates successfully, so serialize and serialize gets called.
- The application gets redirected to /profiles which is what is desired, but the req is empty.  I was expecting the deserialize data to appear somewhere in the req.body, but i'm not seeing that

I'm probably overlooking something small,
Any help appreciated,
Thanks,
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K nevermind. Found the answer.

It's stored under req.session.passport...